# Checked radio buttons not working right in jQuery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I Have a registration form that allows the user to sign up as one of two types of users.The selection is made by selecting a radio button where depending on the radio button chose,will show different registration forms via a jquery modal dialog pop-up.

My problem is that currently the radio buttons are working, and the modal dialogs are displaying properly.**HOWEVER**, upon calling the other dialog, the radio buttons are not updated(i.e they do not represent the current dialog being shown.) even though the dialogs are changing.(Example provided in JsFiddle link below)

E.g. When clicking Register for the first time, the dialog shows, and the user is able to click "Business" and it will switch over without any problems.HOWEVER, after that, when the user tries to switch back to "User" again, the radio button will not switch back to display that "User" is chosen even though the dialog has already switched to the "User" dialog.

How do i ensure that the radio buttons correspond to the dialogs being shown?

HTML(Extract):

```
     <form id='Login' name='Login' method='post' action='login.php'>
    <table id='MainPage' name='MainPage' border='1'>

        <tr>
            <td><label for='LoginEmail'>Email:</label></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='Login' id='LoginEmail' name='LoginEmail' size='50' maxlength='50'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for='LoginPassword'>Password:</label></td>
            <td><input type='password' class='Login' id='LoginPassword' name='LoginPassword' size='50' maxlength='60'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><span id='Register' name='Register' class='Registration' >Register </span></td>
            <td><span id='ForgotPassword' name='ForgotPassword' class='Registration' >&nbsp Forgot Password</span></td>

            <td><input type='submit' name='LoginSubmit' id='LoginSubmit' value='Login'></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>




<div id='CreateUserForm' name='CreateUserForm' class='ModalDialog'>
    <form id='UserCreate' name='UserCreate' action='registeruser.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class='UserCreateField'>
        I would like to register as a :
        <label for='UserCreateUser'>User</label>
        <input type='radio'  name='UserCreateType' id='UserCreateUser' value='User' checked />

        <label for='UserCreateBusiness'>Business</label>
        <input type='radio'  name='UserCreateType' id='UserCreateBusiness' value='Business' />
    </div><br />

    <div class='UserCreateField'>
        <label for='UserCreateEmail'>Email:</label>
        <div class='UserCreateInput'><input type='text' size='50' name='UserCreateEmail' id='UserCreateEmail' /></div>
        <span>dasdasdasdasdasdsadasdasdasdasdadsaddsadsaddsa</span>
    </div><br />

    <div class="UserCreateField">
        <label for="UserCreateConfirmEmail'">Confirm Email:</label>
        <div class="UserCreateInput"><input type="text" size="50" name="UserCreateConfirmEmail" id="UserCreateConfirmEmail"></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='UserCreateField'>
        <label for='UserCreatePassword'>Password:</label>
        <div class='UserCreateInput'><input type='password' size='50' name='UserCreatePassword' id='UserCreatePassword' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='UserCreateField'>
        <label for='UserCreateConfirmPassword'>Confirm Password:</label>
        <div class='UserCreateInput'><input type='password' size='50' name='UserCreateConfirmPassword' id='UserCreateConfirmPassword' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />


    <div class='ModalButton'>
        <input type="button" id="UserCreateCancel" name="UserCreateCancel" class='ModalDialogButton' value="Cancel">
        <input type="button" id="UserCreateSubmit" name="UserCreateSubmit" class='ModalDialogButton' value="Submit">
    </div>


    </form> 
</div>



<div id='CreateBizForm' name='CreateBizForm' class='ModalDialog'>
    <form id='BusinessCreate' name='BusinessCreate' action='registerbusiness.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        I would like to register as a :
        <label for='BusinessCreateUser'>User</label>
        <input type='radio'  name='BusinessCreateType' id='BusinessCreateUser' value='User' />

        <label for='BusinessCreateBusiness'>Business</label>
        <input type='radio'  name='BusinessCreateType' id='BusinessCreateBusiness' value='Business' checked />
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for='BusinessCreateEmail'>Email:</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><input type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' name='BusinessCreateEmail' id='BusinessCreateEmail' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class="BusinessCreateField">
        <label for="BusinessCreateConfirmEmail'">Confirm Email:</label>
        <div class="BusinessCreateInput"><input type="text" size="50" maxlength='50' name="BusinessCreateConfirmEmail" id="BusinessCreateConfirmEmail"></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for='BusinessCreatePassword'>Password:</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><input type='password' size='50' name='BusinessCreatePassword' id='BusinessCreatePassword' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for='BusinessCreateConfirmPassword'>Confirm Password:</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><input type='password' size='50' name='BusinessCreateConfirmPassword' id='BusinessCreateConfirmPassword' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for='BusinessCreateBusinessName'>Business Name:</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><input type='text' size='50' maxlength='50' name='BusinessCreateBusinessName' id='BusinessCreateBusinessName' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'><!--Category-->
        <label for='BusinessCreateCategory'>Business Category</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><select name='BusinessCreateCategory' id='BusinessCreateCategory'></select></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'><!--SubCategory-->
        <label for='BusinessCreateSubCategory'>Business SubCategory</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><select name='BusinessCreateSubCategory' id='BusinessCreateSubCategory'></select></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for='BusinessCreateBusinessAddress'>Address:</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><input type='text' size='50' maxlength='300' name='BusinessCreateBusinessAddress' id='BusinessCreateBusinessAddress' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for="BusinessCreateDescription">Business Description:</label><br>
        <textarea class='BusinessCreateInput' name='BusinessCreateDescription' id='BusinessCreateDescription' cols='39' rows='5'  maxlength='500' ></textarea>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />

    <div class='BusinessCreateField'>
        <label for='BusinessCreateFileUpload'>DisplayPic:</label>
        <div class='BusinessCreateInput'><input type='file' name='BusinessCreateFileUpload' id='BusinessCreateFileUpload' /></div>
        <span></span>
    </div><br />


    <div class='ModalButton'>
        <input type="button" id="UserCreateCancel" name="BusinessCreateCancel" class='ModalDialogButton' value="Cancel">
        <input type="button" id="UserCreateSubmit" name="BusinessCreateSubmit" class='ModalDialogButton' value="Submit">
    </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#CreateUserForm').hide();
$('#CreateBizForm').hide();



$('#Register').on('click',function(){

    $('#CreateUserForm').dialog("open");

});


$('#CreateUserForm').dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    draggable:false,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true,
    minWidth:400

});

$('#CreateBizForm').dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    draggable:false,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true,
    minWidth:400,
    height:'auto',
    show:"slide"

});

$('#UserCreateBusiness').on('click',function(){

    $('#CreateUserForm').dialog("close");
    $('#CreateBizForm').dialog("open");
    //$('#BusinessCreateBusiness').attr('checked','checked');

});

$('#BusinessCreateUser').on('click',function(){

    $('#CreateBizForm').dialog("close");
    $('#CreateUserForm').dialog("open");
    //$('#UserCreateUser').attr('checked','checked');

});

    });
```

Would appreciate any insights. Thanks

EDIT:Jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5ZM/4/

Comment: What do you mean with "the radio buttons are not updated" ? Can you provide your example at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @reporter I cant seem to make it work in jsfiddle, what i meant was that when i switched disload(eg. from form 1 to form 2, the checked radio button is working, but when i try to click back, the dialog switches, but the radio button does not change.)

Comment: What will happen, if you give each radiobutton in each form the same name? As far as I know, for updating the buttons the browser ignores the id attribute and take only an eye on the name attribute.

Comment: I've already changed the names of the radio buttons in each form to the same name, but nothing new is happening.Ill update the question with regards to the names

Comment: @reporter I've got the jsfiddle up , here is the link   http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5ZM/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form1choice2').on('click',function(){

    $('#1').dialog("close");
    $('#2').dialog("open");
    $("#form1choice2").attr('checked', 'checked');

});

$('#form2choice1').on('click',function(){

    $('#2').dialog("close");
    $('#1').dialog("open");
    $("#form2choice1").attr('checked', 'checked');


});
```

Try this...

Comment: I've already tried what you suggested but nothing seems to be working. =X

Answer (score 0):

Opening modals seems to interfere with the completion of the default radio event. Defer the opening of modals until after your click event finishes:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#2').dialog("open");
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

set modal to false

```
$('#CreateBizForm').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    draggable:false,
    resizable:false,
    modal:false,    <--- here
    minWidth:400,
    height:'auto',
    show:"slide"

});
```